# Django form submit and don't change page

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a form in a view to review products. To review the product, I create a form, but when the user submits his review, I want him to remain on the same page.

This is my url:

```
url(r'^(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', 'reviews.views.single_product'),
```

and this is my form

```
<form class = "form-inline" action = "/text/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<strong><h3>Revise este produto</h3></strong><br>

{% for field in form %}

<font size = "4">

{% if field.field.required %} 
<div class="field-wrapper question-required"> 
{{ field.errors }}
<span class="asterix"> * </span><label class="label-inline">{{ field.label }}</label>
{% else %} 
<div class="field-wrapper"> 
{{ field.errors }}
<label class="form-help-text">{{ field.label }}</label>
{% endif %}
<br />

<div class="">
{{ field }}
</div>

</div>
</li>
</font>

{% endfor %}
<br>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value = "Envia Review"><h4>Pronto!</h4></button>
</form>
```

This is the view that renders the page:

```
def single_product(request, slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product, slug=slug)
    prod = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
    reviews = Review.objects.get(product=prod.id)
    reviewmatrix = {}
    i = 0
    try:
        for rev in reviews:
            reviewmatrix[str(i)] = [[review.review_text]]
            u = User.objects.get(username=rev.user)
            i = i + 1
    except:
        u = User.objects.get(username=reviews.user)
        reviewmatrix[str(i)] = [[reviews.review_text]]

    if request.method=="POST":
        form = responseForm(request.POST, review=review)
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save()
            msg = 'Obrigado por avaliar ' + prod.name
        return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'prod':prod, 'reviews':reviews, 'user':u.first_name, 'msg':msg})    
    else:    
        form = ReviewForm()    
        args = {}
        args.update(csrf(request))
    return render(request, 'product_detail.html', {'prod':prod, 'reviews':reviews, 'user':u.first_name, 'form':form})
```

Comment: That would be done in the view where you process the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) to the same view once you process the form. You should be able to identify the slug from the fields in the form.

Alternatively, you can submit the form to the same view using `action = "."` and you can avoid a redirect to the original page.

Comment: ok, i got the idea, but didn't get how to implement this. Can you specify, please? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Please post the code of the view which handles the form i.e. the `/text/` URL.

Comment: This is the view that shows the form. Please post the code of the view that handles the POST request i.e. the view mapped to `/text/` URL.

Comment: Oh, I don't have any view to do this yet.